# How to fix an icon in a corner of hero banner for responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix an svg icon in the bottom right corner of my hero banner (using flexbox). I am struggling to pin it into the correct position and also need to be able to adjust its position relative to the text and button (its a responsive website and I need to adjust based on screen size). I tried to adjust with the css margin property (left and right), but it does not work well.

```css
.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #333333;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500417148159-68083bd7333a) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hero-title {
  max-width: 17em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: .9;
  padding-left: 93px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: white;
}

.hero-subtitle {
  max-width: 23em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  color: white;
}

.hero-footer {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}


/* button */

.button-primary {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 350px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: .1em solid red;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #333333;
  border: .1em solid #ffffff;
}

#iconheader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

#myicon {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 5vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: url(../images/test_icon.svg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <header id="header">
  </header>
  <header class="hero-header">
    <h1 class="hero-title">Wonderful Day<br>Amazing Forum<br>Great Friends</h1>
  </header>
  <header class="hero-header">
    <h2 class="hero-subtitle">Stackoverflow is the #1 forum among developers. Just ask anyone. </h2>
  </header>
  <footer class="hero-footer">
    <a class="button-primary" href="#">Learn More</a>
    <div id="iconheader">
      <a id="myicon" href="#">Icon</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated! Thank you.

[image: desired icon position]

Comment: Just add   justify-content: space-between; and align-items: flex-end; to your hero-footer class. It'll push your button to the left and to down the bottom

Comment: Thank you, Adam. Your suggestion worked well. I am trying to have the icon in a certain position in the bottom-right corner (adding an image above). I used margin-right: 150px in #myicon to move it slightly left, but the bottom positioning is not working so well. I tried padding-bottom but it caused the text and button move (and they should not). Do you know what is the best way to do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: modify #iconheader bottom and right pixel,  not #myicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set position absolute and zindex high

```
 .hero {
    position: relative;
  } 
  
  #iconheader {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:99999
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

for set a svg icon bottom in right corner use this css rules instead of yours:

```
 #iconheader {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

in this way, the svg is always there

Comment: Thank you, Elia. I tried your snippet and it made the icon disappear way down the page. Perhaps it's because of the margins/padding already set in my hero banner section? I just added a picture above to show what I am trying to accomplish. What do you think is the best way to do this? Thank you.